# style_loader_tag filter is converting special characters even with wptexturize disabled

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using a style_loader_tag filter to preload some gfonts, the problem is that is converting all "&" to "& # 3 8 ;".

I've checked my function and it's outputting html correctly, so I'm really sure that is the filter doing this change.

I've tried by disabling wptexturize on that filter, but it's not working.

```
remove_filter('style_loader_tag', 'wptexturize', 1);
add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'rubik_style_loader_tag_filter', 10, 2);
add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'wptexturize', 11);
```

I've even tried with this:

```
add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false', 1 );
```

but.. still nothing.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the html tags to be skipped using a filter.

Text enclosed in the tags pre, code, kbd, style, script, and tt will be skipped. This list of tags can be changed with the no_texturize_tags filter.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/no_texturize_tags/

```
add_filter( 'no_texturize_tags', 'disable_link_filter', 1, 1 );
function disable_link_filter($filter){
  $filter[] = "link"; //Add Link tag to the skip list
  return filter;
}
```

Edit:
To dump all the filter hooks you can use the following Function

```
function print_filters() {
  global $wp_filter;
  print '<pre>';
  print_r( $wp_filter );
  print '</pre>';
}
```

To call it you can use

```
print_filters();
```

Comment: That's really interesting thank you, but... it's not working :(

Comment: Hmm thats strange, dont think its wptexurize then it must be something else

Comment: I do think so, but really don't know what xD

Comment: You can try dumping all filters and check if any may be affecting the output see new code in the answer